# How to remove most namespaces from input XML in XSLT (nokogiri example)

Tags: ruby, xml, xslt, nokogiri

I have this piece of nokogiri code, thats runs slower then I like on large input.  How would you redo this in XSLT?  Any other ideas to make it run faster?

```
# remove namespaces (other then soapenv) from input xml, and move
# them to type attribute.
# xml is Nokogiri::XML object
def cleanup_namespaces(xml)
  protected_ns = %w( soapenv )
  xml.traverse do |el|
    next unless el.respond_to? :namespace
    if (ns=el.namespace) && 
        !protected_ns.include?(ns.prefix) then
      el['type'] = "#{ns.prefix}:#{el.name}"
      el.namespace = nil
    end
  end

  xml
end
```

The sample **input** I am testing with is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:getAccountDTOResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices"
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

      <getAccountDTOReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
      soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xsi:type="ns2:Account">
        <ns1:ID soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xsi:type="xsd:long">0</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true" />
        <ns1:name xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
        <ns1:parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string" />
      </getAccountDTOReturn>
    </ns1:getAccountDTOResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The expected **output** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <getAccountDTOResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices"
    soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    type="ns1:getAccountDTOResponse">
      <getAccountDTOReturn xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices"
      soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
      xsi:type="ns2:Account">
        <ID soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xsi:type="xsd:long" type="ns1:ID">0</ID>
        <accountNumber xsi:type="soapenc:string"
        type="ns1:accountNumber" />
        <accountType xsi:type="soapenc:string"
        type="ns1:accountType" />
        <clientData xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"
        type="ns1:clientData" />
        <name xsi:type="soapenc:string" type="ns1:name" />
        <parentRef xsi:type="soapenc:string"
        type="ns1:parentRef" />
      </getAccountDTOReturn>
    </getAccountDTOResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This input is a SOAP response.  A tangential question is, what is the
point of the ns1 type namespace in the SOAP response, and is it
reasonable to throw them away completely.  I don't seem to need to
reference them when parsing the response.

Comment: If you want XSLT response, you should post XML input sample and describe a desired result. There are a lot of good XSLT programmers here, but few of them know Ruby.

Comment: If you had sample input and output it would be clearer, and easier to check

Comment: Good point.  I have updated the question with sample input and expecte output.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with XSLT. Retagged.

Comment: @Dmitre Disagree.  The question is about constructing XSLT.

Comment: Although it doesn't transform the document in the way you want, do note that Nokogiri has [`xml_doc.remove_namespaces!`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#method-i-remove_namespaces%21) if you want to nuke all namespaces in the document quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() =
        'http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Against your sample will produce this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getAccountDTOResponse type="ns1:getAccountDTOResponse" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <getAccountDTOReturn soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:Account" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/pw/services/PWServices" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:PWServices">
                <ID type="ns1:ID" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:long">0</ID>
                <accountNumber type="ns1:accountNumber" xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountNumber>
                <accountType type="ns1:accountType" xsi:type="soapenc:string"></accountType>
                <clientData type="ns1:clientData" xsi:type="soapenc:Array" xsi:nil="true"></clientData>
                <name type="ns1:name" xsi:type="soapenc:string"></name>
                <parentRef type="ns1:parentRef" xsi:type="soapenc:string"></parentRef>
            </getAccountDTOReturn>
        </getAccountDTOResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This runs in about half the time of Ruby version.  I changed match condition to be negative match `"*[namespace-uri() !=        'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']"` instead of positive, to match the spirit of the original version.

Comment: @Alex G, yes, I forgot to inverse the logic, thanks for commenting this.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Also `*[not(self::soapenv:*)]` with the correct namespace URI bound would work (You will need `@exclude-result-prefixes` because `xsl:element` instruction honors in scope namespaces.)

Comment: @Alejandro. That's why I chose `fn:namespace-uri()`. Second reason is that I felt it would be more semantic to check nsuri, because it's, well, what matters.

Comment: @Alejandro. Do note I said `more semantic`. I don't mean it's more _correct_.